# Angular error Type string is not assignable to type never

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular, Can someone please help me out with this issue here.

```
export class PersonComponent implements OnInit {

  Schools= [];
  
  constructor() { 
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {

  this.Schools= [
    {Name : "ABD Schoool" , Title : "Colarado"},
    {Name : "CC School" , Title : "Texas"}
  ];

  }

}
```

However, I am getting an error stating 'Type string is not assignable to type never'. What does this mean and how can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
  schools: any[] = [];
```

Without defining the array type, it's by default of type `never`.

Comment: now i get `Type '{ Name: string; Title: string; }' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)
`